# JUnit - testing JdbcSQLException

Tags: testing, junit, sqlexception

This piece of code should assert that the method `updateEmployee(id, name, surname)` throws an `JdbcSQLException` when a negative number is put into the `id` parameter.

```
@Test
void updateEmployeeTC2() {
    di.reset();
    try {
        di.createEmployee("old_name", "old_surname");
        assertThrows(JdbcSQLException.class, () -> di.updateEmployee(1, null, null));

    } catch (EmployeeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but unfortunally this is the JUnit output

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "NAME"; SQL statement:
update colleague set name=?, surname=? where colleagueId=? [23502-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:308)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:726)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Update.update(Update.java:126)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:254)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:158)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:144)
    at it.polito.latazza.dao.ColleagueDAO.update(ColleagueDAO.java:88)
    at it.polito.latazza.data.DataImpl.updateEmployee(DataImpl.java:286)
    at it.polito.latazza.data.TestDataImpl.lambda$updateEmployeeTC2$9(TestDataImpl.java:417)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:2920)
    at it.polito.latazza.data.TestDataImpl.updateEmployeeTC2(TestDataImpl.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

The JdbcSQLException is thrown by the `ColleagueDAO.update()` method

```
public static int update(Colleague c) throws EmployeeException {
        Connection connection = DBManager.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps;
        int result = 0;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("update colleague set name=?, surname=? where colleagueId=?");
            ps.setString(1, c.getName());
            ps.setString(2, c.getSurname());
            ps.setInt(3, c.getId());
            result = ps.executeUpdate();
            if(result == 0) throw new EmployeeException();
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

EDIT: `DataImpl.updateEmployee()`

```
@Override
    public void updateEmployee(Integer id, String name, String surname) throws EmployeeException {
        PersonalAccount pa = PersonalAccountDAO.read(id);
        Colleague c = new Colleague(id, name, surname, pa);
        ColleagueDAO.update(c);
    }
```

Comment: The test calls `updateEmployee(int, String, String)` but you posted the method `update(Colleague)` - what is `updateEmployee`?

Comment: @RolandWeisleder I've added the code

Comment: This most probably means that the Colleage constructor or its getName() method has a bug.

Comment: @JBNizet I've updated the test case, this time I expect a JdbcSQLException to be thrown, but the assert won't catch the launched exception and says that nothing has been thrown.

Comment: Of course it isn't thrown, since you catch it in the update method.